# Keras LSTM Multi input and output model not update after each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm very new to keras and I was following this [doc](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) to produce a multi-input and multi-output model. However, after each epoch, the results remain the same. Could someone point me out where I got stuck in?

My code is something like

```
main_input = Input(shape = (maxlen, ), name="main_input")
x = Embedding(94, 64)(main_input) # dic length = 94
lstm_out0 = LSTM(256, activation="relu", dropout=0.1, 
recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(x)
lstm_out = LSTM(256, activation="relu", dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.2)(lstm_out0)

auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype="int32", name='aux_input')
aux_embed = Embedding(94, 64)(auxiliary_input)
aux_lstm_out = LSTM(256, activation="relu", dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)(aux_embed)
auxiliary_output = Dense(10, activation="softmax", name="aux_output")(lstm_out)

x = keras.layers.concatenate([aux_lstm_out, lstm_out])
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[main_input, auxiliary_input], outputs=[main_output, auxiliary_output])
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss={'main_output': 'binary_crossentropy', 'aux_output': 'categorical_crossentropy'},metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([X_train, X_aux_train], [train_label, aux_train_label], 
            validation_data=[[X_dev, X_aux_dev], [dev_label,aux_dev_label]],
              epochs=10, batch_size=batch_size)
```

The main input is a sequence of chars while the main output is a binary value. The aux input is also a sequence of chars while the aux output is a categorical label.

The output is something like

```
Train on 200000 samples, validate on 20000 samples
Epoch 1/10
200000/200000 [==============================] - 892s - loss: 7.3824 - main_output_loss: 5.8560 - aux_output_loss: 1.5264 - main_output_acc: 0.5186 - aux_output_acc: 0.5371 - val_loss: 9.5776 - val_main_output_loss: 8.0590 - val_aux_output_loss: 1.5186 - val_main_output_acc: 0.5000 - val_aux_output_acc: 0.5362
Epoch 2/10
200000/200000 [==============================] - 894s - loss: 9.5818 - main_output_loss: 8.0586 - aux_output_loss: 1.5233 - main_output_acc: 0.5000 - aux_output_acc: 0.5372 - val_loss: 9.5771 - val_main_output_loss: 8.0590 - val_aux_output_loss: 1.5181 - val_main_output_acc: 0.5000 - val_aux_output_acc: 0.5362
```

I ran > 5 epochs and the results are almost all the same. The input data is prepared through features: sequence.pad_sequences label: to_categorical(for multiclass)

Comment: "However, after each epoch, the results remain the same" - can you show how? What is the expected result?

Comment: @DarkCygnus So basically I ran for ~10 epochs but the output of training accuracy and test accuracy are always the same or only tiny differences. The value is always around 0.5. Also the loss did not change much.

Comment: Can you show such values? How you prepared your data into its variables? Have you tried more epochs? Usually the major changes take place on the first epochs, then it stabilizes asymptotical

Comment: @DarkCygnus Updated in the question!

Comment: I would try to graph it like they do in the [docs](https://keras.io/visualization/), then you can compare if the flow is wrong for some reason. I would also use say a couple thousand training sample, and see if the model gets trained. You have to wait 30 minutes for 2 epochs to see no change, maybe with that much data you would have to wait 30 epoch to see a change

Comment: @djk47463 I waited for 10 epochs without any changes and normally it should change. I then changed my second input to the same as my first input and switched that from categorical_crossentropy to binary_crossentropy and it works. However, I still cannot solve my task here.

Comment: Did you plot the network to make sure it’s structed correctly?? 10 epoch May not be nearly enough to witness a change is loss. I have made similar comments in the past, and asker found their network didn’t start training until after 50 epochs. Which is why I suggest you drop the train size, for now, and train it faster on more epochs. Remember you are training 2 loss functions, this is a complex network. While some train fast other train slow which is why google trains there’s for long periods of time, on parallel gpus

Comment: @djk47463 I will try. Thanks!